# Problem in using pre-trained weights in AlexNet (Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm using Keras to train an AlexNet model for speech data.
I'm going to use this model to predict a number using some wav files as input.
I've read similar topics here like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53897220/using-pre-trained-weights-in-alexnet-model-in-keras) but my problem is different. My model weights have different shapes from the pre-trained weights'. 
My pre-trained weights are from [bvlc_alexnet.npy](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~guerzhoy/tf_alexnet/). here are my weights VS the pre-trained weights for conv layers :

```
conv 1 : (11, 11, 3, 96)  vs (11, 11, 3, 96)
conv 2 : (5, 5, 96, 256)  vs (5, 5, 48, 256)
conv 3 : (3, 3, 256, 384) vs (3, 3, 256, 384)
conv 4 : (3, 3, 384, 384) vs (3, 3, 192, 384)
conv 5 : (3, 3, 384, 256) vs (3, 3, 192, 256)
```

here is my model:

```
    model = Sequential()
# 1st Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=96, input_shape=(277, 277, 3), kernel_size=(11, 11), strides=(4, 4),  padding="valid"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="valid"))

# 2nd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(11, 11), strides=(1, 1), padding="valid"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="valid"))

# 3rd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding="valid"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

# 4th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding="valid"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

# 5th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding="valid"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="valid"))

# Fully Connected layers
model.add(Flatten())
# 1st Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(4096, input_shape=(277 * 277 * 3,)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# 2nd Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# 3rd Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(1000))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# Output Layer
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You **can't use** the pre-trained weight if your model is different. if you are referring to **transfer learning**, you need the exact same model and you could only connect **output layer from pre-trained weights** to **new layers you added as input**

Details explanation:
Inside a neural network as neurons forward into layers, a dot product of weight and input (adding bias if needed) is being calculated and forward propagated into **corresponds connected neurons**, adding **even one neuron** or changing the input metrics by a little could result in a **total different output** (hence totally different weight if retrained) from the neural network, so it is **very hard (but not impossible)** to trim less important neurons down within layer and **still be able to get the neural network to work** as before it was trim.

[image: Neural network architecture]

Model I used before for voice classification

```
model = Sequential()
input_shape=(128, 128, 1)

model.add(Conv2D(24, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((4, 2), strides=(4, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(48, (5, 5), padding="valid"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((4, 2), strides=(4, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(48, (5, 5), padding="valid"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.8))

model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.8))

model.add(Dense(num_of_class))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

I used batch size 64 to train and accuracy is 80%+

Comment: Does that mean that I can never use pre-trained weights using AlexNet in Keras? Because there is no pre-trained model for AlexNeit in Keras library.

Comment: Yes, because your model is different, and don't even bother spend time to dig into trimming pre-trained weight down to fit your own model, not worth the time. Just train with your own data from scratch, it won't take that long anyway and it is definitely better!!!

Comment: You should look into wavenet classification, as I think using Alexnet from speech is not giving you high accuracy enough (depends on how complicated your data is).

Comment: Problem is that I have few data and the accuracy is very low (12%) that's why I needed pre-trained weights.

Comment: Trust me, it is not going to help much, and did you convert it into a wav file?

Comment: I didn't convert it, I converted my wav files into spectrogram arrays (RGB images), then I used them as input.

Comment: convert it into .wav and you should be able to load it up. Could you post an image of your spectrogram and what interval of the sound are you using? More than 4 seconds I think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205308/discussion-between-justin-kwan-and-rezasys).